# What is the ultimate limit of horizontal visibility in Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: earth-observation

When meteorological conditions are favorable for generally unlimited visibility, does that mean the atmosphere is sufficiently clear under these conditions that horizontal visibility is truly unlimited?  Or is there a limit to the distance we can see under such conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "see the horizon"?

Comment: this sounds like a worldbuilding question, since this would only be answerable if you knew the properties of the flat world.

Comment: Afraid it's a bit late for the edit, as the answer doesn't match, and the user seems to have gone away

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Horizontal visibility, in essence the distance we could see in a horizontal direction, would simply fade into the distant haze. The ultimate distance we could likely see given exceptionally clear, daylight conditions, would be about 300 km, more or less, due to Rayleigh scattering.